# Filter ng-repeat to create comma separated list of array values from object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a comma delimited string to display in a single table cell using AngularJS (v1.4.8), but the source is a array property within an array of objects.  Similar questions have been asked and are all over SO, but none have steered me in the right so far.

Given an simple array of objects such as the following:

```javascript
$scope.activities = [
  {
    name: "leela",
    entries: [{note: 'Lala-A', isInterested: true }, 
              {note: 'Lala-B', isInterested: false}, 
              {note: 'Lala-C', isInterested: true }]
  }, 
  {
    name: "slurms",
    entries: [{note: 'Blah-A', isInterested: false}, 
              {note: 'Blah-B', isInterested: true}, 
              {note: 'Blah-C', isInterested: true}]
  }];
```

Each object has a property called *entries* which is an array of objects with a boolean value *isInterested*.  I would like to create a comma separated list of the note properties but only for those values of the entries property for which *isInterested = true*;

For example, based on the data above I want to display the following:

```
---------------------------
|NAME    |ENTRIES         |
===========================
|leela   |Lala-A, Lala-C  |
---------------------------
|slurms  |Blah-B, Blah-C  |
---------------------------
```

I have gotten this far, which does filter the properties correctly, but placing them on the same line is the issue:

```html
<!-- this displays the 'note' on multiple lines -->
<div ng-repeat="activity in activities">
  <div ng-repeat="entry in activity.entries | filter:{isInterested: 'true'}">
    <span>{{entry.note}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- this displays nothing/zilch -->
<div ng-repeat="activity in activities">
  <div ng-repeat="entry in activity.entries | filter:{isInterested: 'true'}">
    <span>{{entry.note + ($last ? '' : ', ')}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notes appear on multiple lines because a `div` by default is `display:block;` which will take up as much space as possible. You can fix this by changing the display of your entry div's or you could just change the `div` to a span like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="activity in activities">
  <span ng-repeat="entry in activity.entries | filter:{isInterested: 'true'}">
    {{entry.note + ($last ? '' : ', ')}}
  </span>
</div>
```

This works because the default display of a `span` is `inline`. Working example: https://jsbin.com/jivoqeqade/edit?html,css,js,output